# SQL query statement for two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have two tables

- hh-memberQ
- householdQ

They all contain

```
hh_uuid  
UUID
```

respectively I want to find all UUIDs in HH_UUIDs

Comment: What query have you written so far? Post your code

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Side note: having `-` in the name of a table will just force you quote the name every time you use it.

Comment: I've had a look at your previous questions and you're always reluctant to say the database engine. I found SQL Server 2014 lost in one of your comments so I've assumed it's that.

Comment: You haven't even asked a question. It seems you want us to write the query. This is not what SO is for. *You* should write a query and then come here, if you have any concrete issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner join

```
SELECT hlq.UUID FROM hh-memberQ hq INNER JOIN householdQ hlq ON hq.hh_uuid=hlq.UUID
```

Thus you will get results only in case of an hlq uuid is present on hq

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all `hh_uuid, UUID` from all those tables you can use UNION SELECT like as following in MySQL:

```
SELECT hh_uuid, UUID FROM hh-memberQ
UNION
SELECT hh_uuid, UUID FROM householdQ
```

Comment: they are not having equal umber of expression in their target list so how do i go abt it

Comment: @dusseyrichmond you see many are suggesting you to write detail about your question. Don't you know how to edit your question. I would recommend you to edit your question and try to add the following:
1) What database are you using.
2) Describe the full structure of your 2 tables.
3) Write what query are you trying to get the expected result.